# Global AwesomeAlert on React-native

Tags: react-native, notifications, components, alert, global

i want call my alert everywhere i am in my program so, i have to do a component.

What i want and the problem : I need an alert in almost all pages but , i can't use redux because i won't render the alert everywhere, when he's only call on 1 page.

The problem: I import my component, i can't set the state from this component.

this is the render of my Alert component :

```
     render() {
 const {showAlert} = this.state;
 return (
     <AwesomeAlert
        show={showAlert}
        showProgress={false}
        title="Attention"
        message= {this.messageAlert}
        closeOnTouchOutside={true}
        closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
        showCancelButton={true}
        cancelText="Ok"
        cancelButtonColor="#798078"
        messageStyle = {styles.alertMessageStyle}
        titleStyle = {styles.alertTitleStyle}
        onCancelPressed={() => {
          this.hideAlert();
        }}
      />
 );
```

}

Now Constructor and fonction :

```
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
          this.messageAlert = 'Caliss'
      this.state={
          showAlert: false
      }
  }

  showAlert = () => {
  this.setState({
    showAlert: true
  });
};

hideAlert = () => {
  this.setState({
    showAlert: false
  });
};
```

Render In my current file :

```
render() {
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                   <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this._verifyExistUser} >Login</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
<Alert/>
}
```

My function to verif user In my current file and call the alert if he has an error :

```
_verifyExistUser(){
 if(this.state.user == ''){
   //alert("Vous devez obligatoirement entré un nom d'utilisateur ou votre courriel");
   this.messageAlert = "Vous devez obligatoirement entré un nom d'utilisateur ou votre courriel"
   this.props.showAlert();
 }
 else if(this.state.password == '') {
   this.messageAlert = "Vous devez obligatoirement entré un mot de passe"
   this.showAlert();
 }
 else {
   alert(this.state.user);
 }
```

}

The problem: This.showAlert is not a function... undefined.

1- I can't export this function, i need the state "showAlert"

2- If i have the state showAlert, he won't show because this.showAlert is the state from the
component.

What can i do to import my component in each file i need and to call my functions showAlert and hideAlert to set the state in my current file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use React Hooks. set this alert in your root file like App.js and render from there. change his state using react hooks.